# How to add a Role when a member join in a Guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord, discord.py

Hey I am trying to add a role if the memeber joins with the `on_member_join event`

My code is this

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    gu_id = int(member.guild.id)
    a = gu.find_one({"_id": gu_id}) # I use mongodb and find the guild
    role_name = str(a['role'])
    role = member.guild.get_role(role_name)
    print(role_name)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

But I always get this error

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'*

I also tryed this with the role id but then I get this error

*discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Guild.get_role` takes the ID of the role, you're passing the name. So it makes sense if you try passing the ID, if you still want to pass the name:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="some name")
```

Note that it is case-sensitive

The other error essentially means that the bot doesn't have the necessary permissions to add the roles, either it's too low in the hierarchy, doesn't have the necessary perms or you're the owner of the server and the bot simply cannot add roles to you.

Comment: I used it like you shown me but i got the same error

Comment: I already explained the second error in the answer.

Comment: no when get not the second error i get this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Are you sure you’re typing the correct name? It’s case sensitive

Comment: I don't know why but now it workes i only get the discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions error I give the Bot all Permissions including Admin

Comment: I also told you that if you’re the owner the bot won’t be able to add you the roles

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `gu_id` is trying to assign the `id` value from `member.guild` but it (whatever `guild` is) doesn't actually have that property, or it's not being passed in somewhere in some other logic before this snippet is reached.

Maybe you can try checking how `member.guild` is being used elsewhere first is where I'd start.